# Jquery UI dialogue accessibility (screen reader) issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a simple jquery ui dialogue like below :

```
<div class="error" id="errorMsg" role="dialog" > </div>
```

I have a login form below this and i use this `id="errorMsg"` to display a popup.

```js
 function alertDialogue(output_msg, title_msg) { 
        if (!title_msg)
            title_msg = 'Error';
    
        if (!output_msg)
            output_msg = 'No Message to Display.';    
    
        $("#errorMsg").html(output_msg).dialog({
            title: title_msg,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
    
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() 
                {
                 dialogueON = 0;
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });    
    }
```

When the popup is displayed, it just reads out <kbd>Ok</kbd> button. I want the screen reader to read the error title, error message and the buttons present.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any initial issue with your code. I tested it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/avw0r0yd/

**HTML**

```
<form id="loginForm">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>User:</label>
      <input id="user" type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Pass:</label>
      <input id="pass" type="password">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button id="submitBtn" type="submit">
    Login
  </button>
</form>

<div class="error" id="errorMsg" role="dialog"> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
form ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

form ul li label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function alertDialogue(output_msg, title_msg) {
  console.log("Alert, " + title_msg + ": " + output_msg);
  if (!title_msg)
    title_msg = 'Error';

  if (!output_msg)
    output_msg = 'No Message to Display.';

  $("#errorMsg").html(output_msg).dialog({
    title: title_msg,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,

    buttons: {
      "Ok": function() {
        dialogueON = 0;
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
}

$(function() {
  $("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form submitted.");
    var user = $("#user"),
      pass = $("#pass");
    if (user.val().length === 0 || pass.val().length === 0) {
      alertDialogue("User or Pass Missing!", "Login Error");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

This appears to work as expected with jQuery 3.1.1 and jQuery UI 1.12.1. I would check your browsers console to see if there are errors there. `dialogueON` is undefined in this example.

Comment: It works as expected. i am having issue with accessibility(screen reader). did you check it ?

Comment: @abhilashk no, I did not. You never mentioned that in your post. Please clarify or update your post with a more complete question, maybe include steps to replicate the issue.